# Find an open set whose pre-image is not open for this function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined as

$f(x) = cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x \not = 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

I would like to find an open set in the codomain who's preimage isn't open. I'm convinced one exists because my function isn't continuous at $x=0$ (right?)

Can someone give me such a set?

Thanks

Comment: The value at the point of discontinuity is $0$. So you should look at open sets containing $0$.

Comment: $[-a,a]$, $|a|<1$.

Comment: But if I have a set $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ (or $(0,\epsilon)$) where $\epsilon > 0$ then my function will take every value in the interval $[0,1]$ due to how fast the function oscillates near 0, and then my pre-image will be $\mathbb{R}$. Is this thinking flawed here?

Comment: For $|a|<1$ the points where $\cos(1/x)=1$ are not going to be in the preimage of $[-a,a]$. These points accumulate at zero, so the preimage contains zero, but not a neighborhood of it.

Comment: @Karene, I think you mean $(-a,a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $0<r<1$, and consider $U=(-r,r)$. Show that for any open interval $I$ containing $0$, $f(I)\not\subseteq U$.